# SonataAdmin - How to add custom logic before displaying specific actions links

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I know we can customize the action links we want in ou view list in our entity admin class thanks to :

```
$listMapper
    ->addIdentifier('name')
    ->add('minRole')
    ->add('_action', null, [
        'actions' => [
            'show' => [],
            'edit' => [],
            'delete' => []
        ]
    ])
;
```

or manage the roles thanks to the service : `sonata.admin.security.handler.role`

In my case I would like to add a domain logic in order to display or not the delete button (it appears in the **view list** and the **edit view**).

```
{% if attribute(object, hasEvents) is defined and not object.hasEvents %}
   # display it
{% endif %}
```

I don't know how to override the twig templates of Sonata in order to do that. Only two entities are concerned : `Event` and `Post`.

**EDIT**

for the **view list** I directly override the `list__action_delete.html.twig` template (I created `app/Resources/SonataAdminBundle/views/CRUD/list__action_delete.html.twig`) and this is the code (I know it's not the best way...):

```
{#

The template override the basic one in order to prevent the display of the delete button (in the view list) for the entities
Post and Event. We only display it if they don't have associated activities.

#}
{% if admin.isGranted('DELETE', object) and admin.hasRoute('delete') %}
    {% if not attribute(object, 'isDeleteable') is defined %}
        <a href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('delete', object) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default delete_link" title="{{ 'action_delete'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            {{ 'action_delete'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}
        </a>
    {% else %}
        {% if object.isDeleteable %}
            <a href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('delete', object) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default delete_link" title="{{ 'action_delete'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                {{ 'action_delete'|trans({}, 'SonataAdminBundle') }}
            </a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show you a solution with the edit template as example. You should follow the same approach to search for any other parts / blocks / templates you want to override.

What you want to do is override / extend the **formactions** block of the  edit template. The block is defined in the **base_edit_form.html.twig** template of the sonata admin bundle:

```
vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Resources/views/CRUD/base_edit_form.html.twig
```

To override the template there are different approaches. You can use the approach like described in the [symfony doc about how to override any part of a bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/overriding.html) or you can use the [config options to override the path for some of the sonata templates as described in the docs](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/templates.html#configuring-templates).

I recommend to use the latter. Let's say you have an **AppBundle** and want to use that to override the template. Add these lines to your sonata config section in the `app/config/config.yml` file:

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
        edit: AppBundle:CRUD:edit.html.twig
```

Create the file `src/AppBundle/Resources/views/CRUD/edit.html.twig` and copy the the **formactions** block from the 
`vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Resources/views/CRUD/base_edit_form.html.twig` template into it. Do not forget to extend the **base_edit.html.twig** template (first line) shipped with sonata bundle:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list.html.twig' %}

{% block formactions %}
    ...
{% endblock formactions %}
```

Find the delete button in the **formactions** block and add your custom if statement of do whatever manipulation you wanted to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear answer, for the edit page it works perfectly but I used the `sonata_form_actions` block instead :)